# Reads object inside object as undefined

Tags: javascript, class, object, undefined

I'm trying to make a Pokemon-style game where you hatch and evolve dragons. Most dragons have a more powerful dragon that they evolve into.

https://jsbin.com/pulawoz/15/edit?html,js,output

When I created the "evolve" function, I ran into trouble. It always reads the evolvesInto property of the dragon being evolved (dragonToEvolve) as undefined.

You can see the problem code here:

```
var dragons = [];
var enemyDragon;

function Dragon(name, ATK, maxATK, HP, maxHP, normalPowers, continuousPowers,
    responsePowers, type, cry, evolvesInto, numberOfAttacks) {

    this.name = name;
    this.ATK = ATK;
    this.HP = HP;
    this.maxATK = maxATK;
    this.maxHP = maxHP;
    this.normalPowers = normalPowers;
    this.continuousPowers = continuousPowers;
    this.responsePowers = responsePowers;     
    this.type = type;        
    this.cry = cry;        
    this.evolvesInto = evolvesInto;        
    this.numberOfAttacks = numberOfAttacks        
}

// Dragons

var lusterDragon = new Dragon("Luster Dragon", 1900, 1900, 2500, 2500, [],
   [], [], "Wind", "Shining Emerald Blast! Sha-shing!", lusterDragon2, 1);

var lusterDragon2 = new Dragon("Luster Dragon 2", 2400, 2400, 3100, 3100, [], 
    [], [], "Wind", "Ultimate Emerald Blast! Shaka-shing!", null, 1);

var wattailDragon = new Dragon("Wattail Dragon", 2500, 2500, 3000, 3000, [], 
    [], [], "Light", "Shock Bolt! KRAKA-THOOM!", null, 1);

var babyDragon = new Dragon("Baby Dragon", 1200, 1200, 1800, 1800, [], [], 
    [], "Wind", "Mini Fang! Chomp!", thousandDragon, 1);

var thousandDragon = new Dragon("Thousand Dragon", 2400, 2400, 3500, 3500, 
    [], [], [], "Wind", "Thousand Fang! Chomp!", null, 1);

var alexandriteDragon = new Dragon("Alexandrite Dragon", 2000, 2000, 2400, 
    2400, [], [], [], "Light", "Diamond Blast! Sha-shing!", null, 1);

var hyozanryu = new Dragon("Hyozanryu", 2100, 2100, 3800, 3800, [], [], [], 
    "Light", "Diamond Blade! Shing!", lightEndDragon, 1);

var labradoriteDragon = new Dragon("Labradorite Dragon", 0, 0, 4500, 4500, 
    [], [], [], "Dark", "...", darkEndDragon, 1);

var darkEndDragon = new Dragon("Dark End Dragon", 2600, 2600, 4000, 4000, 
    [darkDrain], [], [], "Dark", "Infernal Force! OOOOOOOOOM!", null, 1);

var lightEndDragon = new Dragon("Light End Dragon", 2600, 2600, 4000, 
    4000[lightBlast], [], [], "Light", "Shining Force! OOOOOOOOM!", null, 1)

var cyberDragon = new Dragon("Cyber Dragon", 2100, 2100, 2700, 2700, [], [], 
    [], "Light", "Cyber Burst! FWOOOOM!", cyberTwinDragon, 1);

var cyberTwinDragon = new Dragon("Cyber Twin Dragon", 2800, 2800, 3600, 3600, 
    [], [], [], "Light", "Cyber Burst v2! FWOOOOM!", cyberEndDragon, 2);

var cyberEndDragon = new Dragon("Cyber End Dragon", 4000, 4000, 5000, 5000, 
    [cyberPierce], [], [], "Light", "Ultimate Cyber Burst! FWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOM!", 
    null, 1)

var cyberDragonDrei = new Dragon("Cyber Dragon Drei", 1800, 1800, 2600, 2600, 
    [], [], [], "Light", "Cyber Burst! FWOOM!", cyberDragonNova, 1);

var cyberDragonNova = new Dragon("Cyber Dragon Nova", 2100, 2100, 3000, 3000, 
    [cyberUpgrade], [], [], "Light", "Helios Cyber Burst! FWOOOM!",
    cyberDragonInfinity, 1);

var cyberDragonInfinity = new Dragon("Cyber Dragon Infinity", 2100, 2100, 
    3000, 3000, [cyberAbsorb], [cyberGain], [cyberCancel], "Light", 
    "Infinite Cyber Burst! FWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOM!", 
    null, 1);

var evolveAsk = function(){
    var selectedDragon = prompt("Which dragon do you want to evolve?");
    var dragonToEvolve = selectedDragons[selectedDragon-1];

    console.log(dragonToEvolve.name + " selected.");

    dragons.shift(dragonToEvolve);

    console.log(dragonToEvolve);

    dragons.push(dragonToEvolve.evolvesInto);            
};

var evolvePrint = function(){
    console.log(selectedDragons);          
    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < dragons.length; i++) { 
        if(dragons[i].evolvesInto !== null){
            console.log("Press " + (i+1) + " to select " + dragons[i].name);
            selectedDragons.push(dragons[i]);
        }
    }          
};

var selectedDragons = [];

var evolve = function(){          
    selectedDragons = [];
    evolvePrint();

    setTimeout(function(){
        evolveAsk();
    },1000);
}
```

I'm a noob, so there might be something obvious I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S.
If you want to test it, enter these commands:

```
dragons.push(lusterDragon);
evolve();
```

Then press 1 and enter.

Comment: if you view the dragons array after resolving the evolve function, it shows "undefined" as a value.

Comment: well, in this case you just need to declare `lusterDragon2` before `lusterDragon`

Comment: how exactly would you do so? I'm a noob.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things confusing with your `evolvesInto` into property. For `lusterDragon` it's an array, for other dragons it's a variable.

We need to make this consistent. The simplest solution to turn all your variables into strings:

`var lusterDragon = new Dragon("Luster Dragon", 1900, 1900, 2500, 2500, [], [], [], "Wind", "Shining Emerald Blast! Sha-shing!", 'lusterDragon2', 1);`

If you want to keep it as a nested object (which I think you want) you'll need to define `lusterDragon2` first, example Fiddle here: https://jsbin.com/nevaqicaro/1/edit

As it is now, it'll be undefined since variable `lusterDragon2` hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Sure thing, please accept this answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely one way to do it with the strings like @Joseph Cho was saying then you could have a handler that picked the evolvable type or you could extend the class from another class.

what @Rudolf Manusachi was saying and I think the first issue is that your evolved types are not defined before your unevolved types and therefore cannot be passed into your object constructors

Check it->
[example jsbin](https://jsbin.com/hivego/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
// Dragons
// luster 2 is now first ->
// to not have undefined they need to be defined before you may use them
// should probly happen with all evolvable dragon types 
var lusterDragon2 = new Dragon("Luster Dragon 2", 2400, 2400, 3100, 3100, [], [], [], "Wind", "Ultimate Emerald Blast! Shaka-shing!", null, 1);
var lightEndDragon = new Dragon("Light End Dragon", 2600, 2600, 4000, 4000, [lightBlast], [], [], "Light", "Shining Force! OOOOOOOOM!", null, 1);
var thousandDragon = new Dragon("Thousand Dragon", 2400, 2400, 3500, 3500, [], [], [], "Wind", "Thousand Fang! Chomp!", null, 1);

var lusterDragon = new Dragon("Luster Dragon", 1900, 1900, 2500, 2500, [], [], [], "Wind", "Shining Emerald Blast! Sha-shing!", [lusterDragon2], 1);
```

This is a perfect use case for object inheritance or if you are feeling it, es6 classes and extension, which are sort of the same thing:  [Obj Constructors/ Inheritance](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/basic-inheritance-with-javascript-constructors.html)